# How to display queryString without array

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an ORM, I have a function to get a queryString but I got an error

"Notice: Array to string conversion"

I don't know how to solve it.
If you can help me, it's could be very nice, thanks

```
public function selectOrderBy($columnName,$order){

    $req = $this->getConnexion()->query('SELECT * FROM '.$this->getTable().' ORDER BY '.$columnName.' '.$order.'');
    $req->execute();
    $this->logRequest($req->queryString);
    $results = $req->fetchAll();
   return $results;
}

 function logRequest($query){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $filePath =  "request.log";
    $fp = fopen($filePath, "a+");
    fputs($fp, "[".date('d/m/Y à H:i:s',time())."]" . $query );  //Error here
    fclose($fp);
}
```

On file request.log I've got this

```
[04/01/2019 à 10:18:05]SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC
[04/01/2019 à 10:18:05]SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC
[04/01/2019 à 10:18:05]Array
```

And I use this in other file

```
$manager->logRequest($manager->selectOrderBy('id','ASC'));
```

Comment: Please ALWAY show ALL the error message, not a summary. Also identify the line in the code that is mentioned on the error message

Comment: I'm sorry, this error is for this line -> fputs($fp, "[".date('d/m/Y à H:i:s',time())."]" . $query );

Comment: Can you dump `$query`

Comment: _Small Point_ the `date()` function does not require the `time()` parameter unless that is not the current time

Comment: fyi, if this is MySQL, the `general_log` will give you exactly what you want. Dont roll your own.

Comment: I edit I forgot to say that I use $manager->logRequest($manager->selectOrderBy('id','ASC'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its sames you `$query` var its an array so you can just use :

```
public function selectOrderBy($columnName,$order){

    $query='SELECT * FROM '.$this->getTable().' ORDER BY '.$columnName.' '.$order.'';
    $req = $this->getConnexion()->query($query);
    $req->execute();
    $this->logRequest($req->queryString);
    $results = $req->fetchAll();
    $array['results']=$results;
    $array['query']=$query;
   return $array;
}
 function logRequest($query){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $filePath =  "request.log";
    $fp = fopen($filePath, "a+");
    fputs($fp, "[".date('d/m/Y à H:i:s',time())."]" . $query );  //Error here
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Other page

```
$manager->logRequest($manager->selectOrderBy('id','ASC')['query']);
```

to use it in onother place you can just change `$manager->selectOrderBy('id','ASC')['query']` with `$manager->selectOrderBy('id','ASC')['results']`

Comment: I have this Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in the same line I've got this error

Comment: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp64\www\myORM\myORM.php on line 83

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\myORM\myORM.php on line 83

Comment: @askemeline is $query equal to return selectOrderBy(..)

Comment: ok now i undertood do you want it like that `SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC` or you want values ?

Comment: Yes, I got this SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC in request.log but with this 2 errors

Comment: yeah great i have the solution now but why you execute query in selectOrderBy when you just need query string not the exection return ,  or you use it on another place ?

Comment: Yes it's because I would like to use it for others functions

Comment: @askemeline ah ok great i updated my answer check it